# android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android

I am facing the following problem:

when a user opens the spinner and presses the home button (without closing the spinner dialog) and resumes the app, it crashes with the following error:

`android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner)`

The spinner adapter is populating correctly the data in the spinner without any problem.

The error only occurs when the user pauses the app (presses the home button) while the spinner dialog is open and then resumes the app.

This is my model class: `Model:`

```
public class DataItem extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

  private String idItem;
  private String wordspinner;
  

  public String getWordspinner() {
    return wordspinner;
  }

  public void setWordspinner(String example_word1) {
    this.wordspinner= wordspinner;
  }
```

Populating the spinner with dataset of words from mysql database in onCreate() method:

```
try {


      ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddActivity.this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataset1);
      niceSpinner_word1.setTitle("select word from spinner");
      niceSpinner_word1.setPositiveButton("close");

      niceSpinner_word1.setAdapter(adp1);
      // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Method onItemSelected:

```
 niceSpinner_word1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        refword1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

      }
    });
```

What i have tried :

1- Implemented serializable to the model class

2- Try/catch the populate spinner code with IO Exception

What should i do ? the app still crashes when the user does the following:

open the spinner

press home button (the spinner dialog is open )
`[crashing here]`

re open the app => the whole app reloads

i am using this library `com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner)`

Maybe a problem in the library code ?

Someone opened an issue in the github repository and there's some comments suggesting some solutions that i didn't know how to implement it :

https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the library itself,

i have checked the issues section on the github repo.

i had to change to another searchable spinner library on github.

https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues/117